# MAC keyboard shortcuts does not always work

Tags: mac, keyboard-shortcuts

Recently moved to MAC (and MAC keyboard) and I am looking to use the shortcuts described in http://osxdaily.com/2012/02/23/keyboard-shortcuts-to-navigate-select-text-mac-os-x/ specifically around navigating and choosing blocks of text.

It appears that generally pressing "Option + Shift + Left/Right" is supposed to select words to the left/right and "Option + Left/Right" is supposed to navigate words.

I'd like for this to work irrespective of what window I am focussed on i.e, Chrome with editing wiki, ms word online/desktop, terminal but it appears this does not work. A good example is trying to edit a wiki page in chrome.

Is there a trick I am missing? Is there a way to enforce the Option button to do the right thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is going to be a tad vague as an answer [no citations] but in general *all apps follow that paradigm*…
with the exception of the ones you mentioned.

The functionality is dependant on the app following the Mac toolbox guidelines, notoriously ignored by Chrome. Word also has its own structure, more akin though not identical to the Windows version & Terminal [any terminal, iTerm, emacs etc, not just the built-in one] has an entirely different set of rules.